# timezone conversion by tz_convert doesn't get saved in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timezone

when I use the following code snippet, I can see that things get converted

```
tweets_df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time']) 

for index, row in tweets_df.iterrows(): 

    row['Time'] = row['Time'].tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern') 
    print(row['Time'])
```

though when I use the following right at the end of it,

```
for index, row in tweets_df.iterrows(): 
    print(row['Time'])
```

It prints back the unconverted one. How should I save the converted version in row['time']?

the Time column has elements like `2016-10-20 03:43:15+00:00`

Comment: Please post an example DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas support vecotorized operations so you don't need the `for` loop:

```
tweets_df['Time'] = pd.Index(pd.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time'], utc=True)).tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

Comment: using your code tweets_df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(tweets_df['Time']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')

# tweets_df['Time'] = tweets_df['Time'].tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
for index, row in tweets_df.iterrows():
    print(row['Time'])
I get this error  https://paste.linux.community/view/a9fd34ad

Comment: @MonaJalal That just means that the index of the DataFrame isn't a datetime... Updated the answer.

Comment: @MonaJalal If you pass `utc=True` to `.to_datetime` you don't need to call `tz_localize`

Answer (score 1):

In the first part of the code, you change the value of row variable at each iteration of the loop, but this does not adjust the row of tweets_df['Time']. If you want to change tweet_df dataframe, then you should modify it as follows:

```
for index, row in tweets_df.iterrows(): 

    tweets_df['Time'].iloc[index] = row['Time'].tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

However, with the following two lines of code you could avoid for loop:

```
tweets_df.Time  = pd.to_datetime(tweets_df.Time, utc=True) 
tweets_df.Time = tweets_df.Time.dt.tz_convert(tz = 'US/Eastern')
```

For a simple dataframe below the result is the following:

```
tweets_df = pd.DataFrame()
tweets_df['Time'] = ['2018-03-01 09:00:00', '2018-03-02 09:00:00', '2018-03-03 09:00:00']
tweets_df.Time  = pd.to_datetime(tweets_df.Time,utc=True) 

print(tweets_df)


                   Time
0 2018-03-01 09:00:00+00:00
1 2018-03-02 09:00:00+00:00
2 2018-03-03 09:00:00+00:00`

tweets_df.Time = tweets_df.Time.dt.tz_convert(tz = 'US/Eastern')

print('Convert to US/Eastern time:\n',tweets_df)

Convert to US/Eastern time:
                        Time
0 2018-03-01 04:00:00-05:00
1 2018-03-02 04:00:00-05:00
2 2018-03-03 04:00:00-05:00`
```

If you want to remove the time zone information while keeping the local time (not converted to UTC):

```
tweets_df.Time = tweets_df.Time.dt.tz_localize(None)

print('Remove time zone information:\n',tweets_df)


Remove time zone information:
                  Time
0 2018-03-01 04:00:00
1 2018-03-02 04:00:00
2 2018-03-03 04:00:00`
```